# Sealing exterior junction box

Tags: electrical

I'm installing an exterior junction box where I'm removing an old light fixture.  I have a gasket to seal the cover to the box.  But how do I seal the hole where the wire goes into the box?

Comment: What wire goes into the box?  Did you remove a wire?  Is there still power by another entrance?  Need more details, but there are plugs for some types of outdoor boxes.

Comment: There's a 2ft romex wire coming out of a hole in the wall.  It used to extend to a light fixture in some nearby steps.  I mounted the box next to the hole and routed the wire through a hole in the bottom of the box.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to fill the hole with something called "duct seal" from my hardware store.  It's like plumber's putty.  I stuffed it in the hole and molded it around the wire.  It seems to seal the hole up pretty well and is supposed to be weather-proof.

In retrospect, I probably should have bought a junction box that has a hole in the back and put it directly over where the wire comes out of the wall.  I noticed that some have caps that can seal unneeded holes but not the model I bought.

Comment: Right; box with hole in back and, ideally a water proof clamp (may have to cut a bigger hole for that.   I usually fill voids with silicone caulk.  This putty sounds good.